# How can I avoid a specific string pattern from being replaced by Regex.replace ()

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string like 
    `Pakistan, officially the <a href="Page.aspx?Link=Islamic Republic of Pakistan">Islamic        Republic of Pakistan</a>`

Now I am using
    `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputText, "(\\bPakistan\\b)", "something");`
to replace Pakistan outside the  tags. But I don't want to replace Pakistan occurring within the `<a></a>` tags. 
Edit: an actual string

> Pakistan (Urdu: پاکِستان), officially
>   the Islamic Republic of Pakistan, is a
>   country in South Asia. It has a
>   1,046-kilometre (650 mi) coastline
>   along the Arabian Sea and Gulf of Oman
>   in the south and is bordered by
>   Afghanistan and Iran in the west,
>   India in the east and China in the far
>   northeast.[6] Tajikistan also lies
>   very close to Pakistan but is
>   separated by the narrow Wakhan
>   Corridor.

And An array of strings

```
string[] links={"Pakistan","Islamic Republic","Republic of Pakistan","South Asia","Arabian Sea","Gulf","Oman","Gulf of Oman","the south","in the south","Afghanistan","Iran","the west","in the west","west India","the east","China","Tajikistan","the narrow","Wakhan Corridor","Central Asia","the Middle","Middle East","the Middle East"}
```

I want to replace every occurrence of every string in this array with `<a href="page.aspx?link=thisString">thisString</a>`. and I could not correctly add links to strings like "Republic of Pakistan" where Pakistan is also another string in this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although @Chris solution does not works exactly here, but you can use in this way.

```
string content = "Pakistan is <a href=\" Pakistan is\">Pakistan an islamic country</a>";
string content2= Regex.Replace(content,@"\bPakistan\b", "India");
string content3 = Regex.Replace(content2, @"(?<=\<\s*a[^<]+)\bIndia\b(?=.*?\>)", "pakistan");        
Console.WriteLine(content3);
```

but this is not a very efficient solution.

Comment: May be not very efficient but easy to understand and implement. Thanks

Comment: I used it like this inputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, @"(?<=\<\s*a[^<]+)\bStringToReplace\b(?=.*?\>)", "DBPT"); inputText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputText, "(\\bStringtoReplace\\b)", Replacement); inputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, @"(?<=\<\s*a[^<]+)\bDBPT\b(?=.*?\>)", StringtoReplace)

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do something in the context of HTML syntax, use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 2):

For the first part of your question, I would match *either* a link *or* the target word:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"<a\s+.*?</a>|\bPakistan\b");
```

Then I would use a MatchEvaluator to check which one I matched and replace accordingly: if it's a link, plug it back in; if it's the target word, linkify it.

For the second part, you can `Join` the strings in the array into a regex alternation, like this:

```
string regex = String.Format(@"\b({0})\b", String.Join("|", links));
```

Just remember that an alternation returns the first matching alternative, not the longest.  If any alternative **A** is a prefix of alternative **B**, **B** should be listed *before* **A**.  For example, `the Middle East` should come before `the Middle` in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do the opposite of what you're asking (replace only the instances inside the tags):

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"(?<=\<\s*a[^>]+)\bPakistan\b(?=.*?\>)", "India");
```

This is very untested and not what you want, but it could give you some hints.  This uses [zero-width lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).  I'm sure there are many other ways to do it.

This is really pushing the limits of regex.  You should probably use an HTML parser.

Edit: using negative lookbehind, this appears to work (please test it!):

```
content = Regex.Replace(content, @"(?<!\<\s*a[^>]+)\bPakistan\b", "India");
```

Comment: Does the C# regex allow variable-width expressions in negative lookbehinds? Most regex engines that support lookbehinds don't allow variable-width expressions (due to not knowing how far back to step to attempt to match them).

Comment: My potentially flawed understanding of "zero-width" was that it meant the assertion captured nothing.  The .NET regex example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#sectionToggle8 appears to use variable-width expressions: "(?<!(Saturday|Sunday) )\b\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4}\b" (the Saturday/Sunday alternation).

Comment: @Dav: .NET is nearly unique among regex flavors in that you can use any expression you like inside a lookbehind.  @Chris: it's more correct to say that a zero-width assertion (like a lookbehind) *consumes* nothing.  Capturing is something else.

Comment: I used it like this
inputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, @"(?<=\<\s*a[^<]+)\bStringToReplace\b(?=.*?\>)", "DBPT"); 
                inputText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(inputText, "(\\bStringtoReplace\\b)", Replacement);
                inputText = Regex.Replace(inputText, @"(?<=\<\s*a[^<]+)\bDBPT\b(?=.*?\>)", StringtoReplace);

Answer (score 0):

Get each line of text into a string `A`

Remove the bit between `<a></a>` and store it in string `B`

Run your `Regex` on the remaining text in string `A`

return `A + B`

Comment: Location of <a></a> tags will be lost.

Comment: No it won't, you need to show a simple code sample with some clear sample data.

Comment: You are right in this string it wont. But  `<a></a>` does not necessarily appear at the end and there are more than one `<a></a>` blocks.

Comment: Yes: so show us some code and some useful test data so we can have a chance of helping you better in all scenarios!